# Woocommerce | Disable hyperlink to product on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I disable the hyperlink of the product image on the cart page.

See below screenshot, highlighted in red.

[image: screenshot]

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: In the future please add the screenshot to the question itself instead of linking. Also, any attempts you have made at solving the question and why they didn't work are helpful.

Answer (score 17):

Add the following filter to your functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_permalink','__return_false');
```

It will remove the product links from your cart page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: This now will link to the front page. I suggest one of the solutions below.

Comment: @JulianWagner it won't. It will just remove the permalink from the product title

Answer (score 4):

Add this:

```
.woocommerce-cart td.product-thumbnail, .woocommerce-cart td.product-name {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

at your custom.css file

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files `cart.php` and `order-details.php` into the theme folder.

In these files you will see print references formatting the links. ie;

under `class=product-name` you see this line:

```
else
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '%s', $_product->get_permalink(), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Here the print line starts with `sprintf` You want to remove the anchor tags surrounding the `%s`. Since you now only have one `%s`, you also remove `$_product->get_permalink(),`

That will get rid of the link for the product name. So the final string of code will look like this:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '%s', $_product->get_title() ));
```

You do the same for `class="product-thumbnail"` in cart.php and `class="product-name"` in order-details.php

[Somebody else had this issue on the WooCommerce Support Forums in the WordPress Repository](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-the-links-on-the-cart-page?replies=2).

Comment: Why override the template when the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter is available?

Comment: It seemed easier to remove the links within the template files and override them, as this is just removing the anchor tags.

Comment: Hi, found out a better way - I just removed href from ahref=

It worked!

Comment: I re-read the question and you are right that you cannot remove the hyperlink via filter. I mistakenly thought you were modifying the name, but ignoring the name which can be modified via filter.

Comment: @slint Better to remove the whole `<a>` tag than to have a link that looks like a link but doesn't do anything. That's poor user experience.

Comment: That's how I actually wanted, as I didn't want the clients to be clicking somewhere else when on that page. But noted for future, thank you.