# Woocommerce – Removing hyperlinks to single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and I would like to remove the hyperlinks to single product pages as i use a quickview feature instead, making content pop up in a lightbox and making single product pages unneeded.

However, the links that are generated in the cart and mini-cart link to the default product page so I would like to remove them.

**What I want to do for the cart page: *Remove the hyperlink to the single product page from the product thumbnail***   I am not a php expert per se, but made some progress following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674698/woocommerce-disable-hyperlink-to-product-on-cart-page). It worked on my product title but it *didn't work on my product thumbnail* in the cart page.

Here is the snippet from my cart.php:

```
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                    <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo $thumbnail;
                        } else {
                            printf( '%s', $thumbnail );
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                        } else {
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '%s',  $_product->get_title() ) );
                        }

                        // Meta data
                        echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                        // Backorder notification
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
```

**What I want to do for the mini-cart: *Remove the hyperlink to the single product page from the product thumbnail and product title***

and the snippet from my mini-cart.php: (Full mini-cart.php code [here](http://codepen.io/scrltt/pen/NABzqV))

```
            <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                            esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                        ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) : ?>
                            <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Both product thumbnail and product title is still hyperlinked despite removing the `<a href>` tag.

Please help!!

screenshot of hyperlinked product title and thumbnail
[image]

Comment: Can you post link to your pages ?

Answer (score 0):

For cart.php
You can change these two lines

replace

```
printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
```

with

```
printf( '%s', $thumbnail );
```

and

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

with

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '%s',  $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

or you can use the filters to get the job done, if you are using a child theme in your child-theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php make the changes .

In mini-cart.php

replace

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
   <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
</a>
```

with

```
<?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
```

page should be at chil-theme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php

The page link you have provided me is the order page, for which the page should be used is order-details-item.php

here you should replace

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
```

with

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '%s', $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
```

let me know if you can share a screenshot of the page, that will be better if it wont work for you or you can allow me to create a fake order , so that I can check it.

if you are facing problem let me know.

Comment: The edits to cart.php worked like a charm, i think there was something wrong with my original php file, so I overwrite it with the default template, made the edits and it worked! Thank you very much for that! 

The edits to mini-cart did not somehow. I tried overwriting with the default template and made the changes you suggested like I did for the cart page, but the product image and title are still hyperlinked.  

I have pasted my edited minicart php file here: http://codepen.io/scrltt/pen/KrBBwW

Comment: @SCRLTT if it is already helpful, please upvote it , I am looking into the codepen snippet .

Comment: Hey Prafulla, followed your edits but it didn't work. I have added a screenshot above for your convenience, thank you so much!

Comment: @SCRLTT I was asking about the total page screenshot not the one you had sent, I can not have a order page with items with out any order and can not create fake orders that is why I asked you for screenshot with URL and whole page , please provide that.